# Printing PDFs with CutePDF or alternate tool via c#

Tags: c#, pdf, automation, ms-word

I am writing an application which will need to produce PDFs from word documents via c#. I believe that this may be possible using CutePDF, although I will welcome suggestions for other tools/APIs. Does anybody have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Word interop is an option, and you have Word 2007 or Word 2010, then you can make Word itself does it for you as normal Save-As.

Example:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412305(v=office.12).aspx

Quoting Sample Code From Above Link:

```
try
{
    // Open the source document.
    wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Open(
        ref paramSourceDocPath, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
        ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
        ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
        ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
        ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
        ref paramMissing);

    // Export it in the specified format.
    if (wordDocument != null)
        wordDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFilePath,
            paramExportFormat, paramOpenAfterExport, 
            paramExportOptimizeFor, paramExportRange, paramStartPage,
            paramEndPage, paramExportItem, paramIncludeDocProps, 
            paramKeepIRM, paramCreateBookmarks, paramDocStructureTags, 
            paramBitmapMissingFonts, paramUseISO19005_1,
            ref paramMissing);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Respond to the error
}
finally
{
    // Close and release the Document object.
    if (wordDocument != null)
    {
        wordDocument.Close(ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
            ref paramMissing);
        wordDocument = null;
    }

    // Quit Word and release the ApplicationClass object.
    if (wordApplication != null)
    {
        wordApplication.Quit(ref paramMissing, ref paramMissing,
            ref paramMissing);
        wordApplication = null;
    }

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
```